# Retrieve options already applied to a holoviews object

Tags: python, holoviews

When I apply options to a holoviews object (Element, Layout, Holomap, ...), is it possible to retrieve those options later on?

```
p=hv.Points(np.random.rand(100,2)).options(width=700, size=10, color='r')
```

Given `p`, (how) can I find `width=700, size=10, color='r'`?

I've gone through all the attributes of `p` and also looked through `StoreOptions` but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to elaborate on the internal API, you can use the following to get an ordered dictionary of the options set:

```
from holoviews import Store
options = Store.lookup_options(Store.current_backend, p, 'style')
options.kwargs
```

where `options` is an `Options` object containing just the 'style' options of object `p` (the distinction between 'style' and 'plot' options are described at the end of the [user guide](http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Applying_Customizations.html)).

Comment: Great! And for those who wonder, `Store.lookup_options(Store.current_backend, p, 'plot').kwargs` would give you the 'plot' options.

Comment: Having tried it in more depth, how would I go about retrieving options in nested objects? Say, if I had a Layout `p*p+p`?

Comment: I think you'll need to index through the layout/overlay to reach the element you want to check the options for. Then you should be able to use the same approach as above.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the printed representation of the options as follows:

```
p.opts.info()
```

Which will print something like:

```
:Points   [x,y]
 | Options(color='r', size=10, width=700)
```

If you need programmatic access to the settings, there is currently no public API (though it is planned). There is an internal API but using that is a little more involved...

Comment: Note this only applies to the latest holoviews version (1.11+)